# Does this identity hold in a heap? $ [x, [a,p,b], [y,c,z]] = [[x,a,y],[b,p,c],z] $

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(mathematics)) $H$, and denote its ternary operation by $[a,b,c]$. Let now $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $p$ be elements of $H$. Is the following identity true?
>   $$[x, [a,p,b], [y,c,z]] = [[x,a,y],[b,p,c],z]$$

For some reason I'm stuck - I cannot come up with either a proof or a counterexample.

Also: I'm not sure how to tag this question appropriately. Please feel free to edit the tags as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a counterexample. Take a group $G$, it has a natural heap structure by
$$
[a,b,c]:= a b^{-1} c .
$$
Suppose now that $G$ is not commutative. Take $a=b=c=x=z=1$, and $p,y$ such that that $py\ne yp$. Then 
$$
[x,[a,p,b],[y,c,z]] = [1,[1,p,1],[y,1,1]] = py ,
$$
and 
$$
[[x,a,y],[b,p,c],z] = [[1,1,y],[1,p,1],1] = yp .
$$

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you wish so that this question does not unnecessarily get bumped by Community.